# can only connect to mysql database with root never with other user

Tags: linux, mysql, lamp

I am running LAMP on ubuntu 19 server running on Virtual Box.

I create additional users with these commands.

```
    mysql>
    CREATE USER 'kat'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'katpw';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'kat'@'localhost';
```

Then FLUSH PRIVILEGES; (or even restart mysql and in extremis VM image)

Then I use this test script:

```
    <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'kat', 'katpw');
    if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

and it never works. However if I use my test script with root login and pw, it works, so clearly I can reach the mysql db. But why does it never work for any additional user I create?

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this up for reference, fixed with

```
    ALTER USER 'kat'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'katpw';
```